# fill cells in a matrix with one and zeros

Tags: r, vector, dplyr, lapply

I have the next problem:

I have a column with some identificators, for instance:

```
 id<-c("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8","id9","id10")
```

then I have have three vectors

```
 v1<- c("id3","id5","id7")

 v2<- c("id1","id2","id10","id8")

 v3<- c("id5","id9","id10","id3")
```

I need to create a table, where the first column is the id column (with all the id´s in the three vectors)

Then I need to add three columns in the table and in each column put a 1 if the respective id appears in the vector, and  0 otherwise.

The expected output is something like this

```
vv1<-c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0)
vv2<-c(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,1)
vv3<-c(0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,1)

output<-  data.frame(id,vv1,vv2,vv3)
```

I need this idea in order to replicate the same with a big vector of id's, around 3M.

Comment: Could you show your expected output based on your given input?

Comment: actually the ids are identification numbers of 10 digits every one, I have around 3.5 million of identifiers and the vectors v1, v2 and v3 are also with 10 digits

Comment: do you have the `v1, v2` is a list/ dataframe?

Comment: I have it stored in lists, v1, v2, v3,.... each one in a list

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your vectors look like

```r
id <-c("id1","id2","id3","id4","id5","id6","id7","id8","id9","id10")

v1 <- c("id3","id5","id7")
v2 <- c("id1","id2","id10","id8")
v3 <- c("id5","id9","id10","id3")

data.frame(id, 
           vv1 = as.integer(id %in% v1), 
           vv2 = as.integer(id %in% v2), 
           vv3 = as.integer(id %in% v3))
```

returns

```r
     id vv1 vv2 vv3
1   id1   0   1   0
2   id2   0   1   0
3   id3   1   0   1
4   id4   0   0   0
5   id5   1   0   1
6   id6   0   0   0
7   id7   1   0   0
8   id8   0   1   0
9   id9   0   0   1
10 id10   0   1   1
```

Comment: But this works for a really big data set? I mean, actually I have 12 columns every column with around 3M of rows and the id column with around 4M

Comment: Good question... I think it could work but there are perhaps better ways...